# How to implement UMAC encryption (RFC 4418) in C#?

Tags: c#, encryption, encryption-symmetric

As I do not want to reinvent the wheel: are there examples, code snippets or implementations of the UMAC encryption according to RFC 4418? Or is it perhaps part of the .NET standard libraries under a different name?

Comment: UMAC is a message authentication code (MAC) standard that uses hashing, not encryption (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UMAC).  The Framework includes direct support for HMAC (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmac), but as far as I know, nothing for UMAC.  If you are looking for a symmetric encryption algorithm, avoid things that end in MAC

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, we need to use UMAC in our project as the data that we need to process is given and cannot be changed (an industrial device). UMAC is hashing _and_ encryption (first hash, then encrypt with a given key), so I think it should work.